# how to get what is in htmlOutput

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have the following flexdashboard

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### 

```{r}
htmlOutput("ui_txt")
output$ui_txt <- renderText({
  "hi there <how@di.how>> sometimes html is just full of <> lovely symbols"
})
```
````

This one basically shows me this
[image]

As you see it strips out the email address which is fine and shows only `"hi there > sometimes html is just full of <> lovely symbols"`

I would like to have a function in R which mimics the htmlOutput such that I can call

```
thatfunction("hi there <how@di.how>> sometimes html is just full of <> lovely symbols")
```

and it returns me `"hi there > sometimes html is just full of <> lovely symbols"`

How should I do that?

Comment: What about: `sub('<.*?>', '', "hi there <how@di.how>> sometimes html is just full of <> lovely symbols")`?

Comment: Regular expressions are not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for an exact reproduction of htmlOutput.